# Recording Gunshots

Tags: microphone

What type of external microphone is best to use to record gunshots? I am looking for a microphone that will give me a high quality and rich detail such as :

Thanks!

Comment: Great example, very good recording of the gun, but when you do it make sure that you have a quiet background, there's a truck engine or generator in this one.

Comment: You might help us out by letting us know if you plan to use it in a video and if you want to record it as a stereo or mono signal. In video, the pan position should copy the position of the gun in the frame, or off-frame.

Comment: I am looking for an external mic for my current video camera (Go pro Hero 2). So I would like it to be stereo. I am fairly new to recording, but I would really like to make the best investment now when it comes to a mic.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you want an external mic for your Go Pro Hero 2 as to improve the audio quality of the internal mic. Go Pro Hero 2 has 3.5mm stereo mic input so the following are compatible Stereo Mics with 3.5mm plug.

Low budget version:
Audio Technica Pro24CM (about $70 at B&H)

[image]

Transducer  Fixed-charge back plate, permanently polarized condenser
Polar Pattern   X/Y Stereo
Frequency Response  100Hz - 17kHz
Dynamic Range (Typical)     82dB, 1kHz at Max SPL
Signal-to-Noise Ratio   57dB, 1kHz at 1 Pa
Maximum Input Sound Level   119dB SPL, 1 kHz at 1% T.H.D.
Power Requirements  2-10VDC plug-in power
Output Impedance    600 ohms
Output Connectors   3.5 mm stereo mini plug on cable
Pad     No
Low Frequency Roll-Off  No
Dimensions (LxDiameter)     4.59 x 0.83" (116.5 x 21mm)
Weight  3.9 oz (111 g)

Here is an example of this mic at work hooked up to a GoPro HD Hero2.
This fella wanted to record the exhaust pipes on his vette, this video convinced me that it did a decent job. I should think it would do well for machine guns too.

"Weather was killer here today, got the microphone mounted up on the frame directly between the mufflers, and ran it to front of car, mounted GoPro on windshield and took it out for a short video...
Sounds amazing! This was with no audio editing either..."

High End Version (about as much as your Go Pro... $299 at B&H)
Rode Stereo VideoMic Pro

[image]

Transducer  Pressure Gradient, JFET impedance converter
Polar Pattern   XY Cardioid (Coincident)
Frequency Range     40Hz ~ 20,000Hz (selectable HPF@75Hz)
Output Impedance    200Ω
Maximum Output  +4.2dBu (@ 1% THD into 1kΩ)
Power Supply    9V alkaline battery
Connection  1/8" (3.5mm) stereo mini-jack
SPL     134dB, max (1 kHz, 1% THD into 1kΩ)
Sensitivity     -38dB re 1V/P (12.6mV @ 94dB SPL) ±2dB @ 1kHz
EIN     20dBA SPL (A - weighted per IEC651)
Dynamic Range   100dB (per IEC651)
Signal to Noise Ratio   73dB SPL (A - weighted per IEC651)
Dimensions  2.6 x 4.25 x 5.1" (66 x 108 x 130 mm)
Weight  4.1 oz (117 g) (without battery)

Famously regarded director of photography, Philip Bloom talks about this mic here:
http://philipbloom.net/2012/01/18/rodesvmp/

Comment: Excellent that answers my question! Thank you very much.

Comment: You are very welcome.